# Apache24, PHP 8.2.1, Twig 3 Templates, Callable functions

Tags: php, twig

I'm working on a PHP website using Twig templating, on the following system specs:

- Window 10 x64 Pro (up to date)
- Apache 2.4.5 x64 for Windows
- PHP 8.2.1 x64 Thread Safe
- Twig 3

I have made a class for routing, referenced in an index.php file at the site root. I also render templates within this index.php file. All is working well, but it would look better and be more manageable, if I could put the Twig rendering into a separate file, namespace and class. This is where things stop working.

The code is as follows:

**.htaccess** file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

A summarised route class

**/src/router.php**

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App {    

    class Router {
        private array $handlers;

        public function get(string $path, callable $callback): void {
            $this->addHandler("GET", $path, $callback);
        }

        private function addHandler(string $method, string $path, callable $callback): void {
            $this->handlers[$method . $path] = [
                'path' => $path,
                'method' => $method,
                'handler' => $callback];
        }

        public function run() {
            $request_uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            $request_path = $request_uri['path'];
            $request_method =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
            $callback = null;

            foreach($this->handlers as $hnd) {

                if (($hnd['path'] === $request_path) && ($hnd['method'] === $request_method)) {
                    $callback = $hnd['handler'];
                    break;
                }
            }

            call_user_func_array($callback, [array_merge($_GET, $_POST)]);
        }
    }
} ?>
```

In my summerised index.php file.

**index.php**

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
    require_once "./src/router.php";
    use App\Router;
    $router = new Router();

    require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
    use \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader;
    use \Twig\Environment;

    $loader = new FilesystemLoader([__DIR__ . "/tpl"]);
    $twig_env = new Environment($loader, ['autoescape'=>false]);

    /* common website paramaters for the twig template */
    $base_data = ['site_title'=>"my-website",
          'site_author'=>"Me Myself & I", 'copy_right'=>"©2023",
          'css_sitewide'=>"http://my-website:8080/static/css/site-wide.css"];

    $home_page = function() use ($twig_env, $base_data) {
        $hp = ['page_title'=>"Home", 'page_desc'=>"Welcome to the my website", 'format_phone'=>"no", 'tell_me'=>"CRIKEY! IT WORKS'"];
        echo $twig_env->render("/index.html", $base_data + $hp);
    };
    $router->get("/", $home_page);

    $contact_page = function() use ($twig_env, $base_data) {
        $cp = ['page_title'=>"Contact", 'page_desc'=>"Get in touch, we'll join ya' in the chat.", 'format_phone'=>"yes", 'tell_me'=>"HELLO! ARE YOU THERE?"];
        echo $twig_env->render("/contact.html", $base_data + $cp);
    };
    $router->get("/contact", $contact_page);

    $router->run();
?>
```

All works quite well. But as the number of routes increase, the page looks more unmanageable. I want to place the rendering in another file and class, while leaving the router get calls on this index.php.

I've made another file and class summerised as such.

**/src/render.php**

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App {
    require_once "/apache24/my-website/vendor/autoload.php";
    use \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader;
    use \Twig\Environment;    

    class Render {
        private static $loader;
        private static $twig_env;
        private static $base_data;

        public static function init(string $tpl) {
            Render::$loader = new FilesystemLoader($tpl);
            Render::$twig_env = new Environment(Render::$loader, ['autoescape'=>false]);
            Render::$base_data = ['site_title'=>"my-website",
                'site_author'=>"Me Myself & I", 'copy_right'=>"©2023",
                'css_sitewide'=>"http://my-website:8080/static/css/site-wide.css"];
        }

        public static function homePage() {
            $hp = ['page_title'=>"Home", 'page_desc'=>"Welcome to the my website", 'format_phone'=>"no", 'tell_me'=>"CRIKEY! IT WORKS'"];
            echo Render::$twig_env->render("/", Render::$base_data + $hp);
        }

    }    
} ?>
```

This is where it stops working. The index.php file for this.
**index.php**

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
    require_once "./src/router.php";
    use App\Router;
    $router = new Router();

    require_once "./src/render.php";
    use App\Render;
    Render::init(__DIR__ . "/tpl");

    $router->get('/', Render::homePage());

    $router->run();
?>
```

The page indeed renders **but** I receive the following error in my php_error.log file,

```
[22-Jan-2023 18:38:16 Australia/Sydney] PHP Fatal error:

Uncaught TypeError: App\Router::get(): Argument #2 ($callback) must be of type callable, null given, 
called in D:\apache24\my-website\index.php on line 11 and defined in D:\apache24\my-website\src\router.php:10

Stack trace:
#0 D:\apache24\my-website\index.php(11): App\Router->get()
#1 {main}
  thrown in D:\apache24\my-website\src\router.php on line 10
```

In the Firefox web developer console I get,

```
GET http://my-website:8080/ [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 19ms]
Status             500 Internal Server Error
Version            HTTP/1.0
Transferred        1.14 kB (908 B size)
Referrer Policy    strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Request Priority   Highest
```

I'm having a guess here from the log file, but I think it's with the render function (public static function homePage()) return type. I can't make this callable.

Any suggestions, or pointers is deeply appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

njc

Comment: `$router->get('/', Render::homePage());` - That will execute `Render::homePage()` immediately and pass the response from that method as the argument (which will be `null` since the method doesn't actually return anything). You need to pass a [callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) (which just references the method so your [call_user_func_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) in the router can execute it when the route matches). It should be `$router->get('/', [Render::class, 'homePage']);`.

Comment: _Side note:_ There are plenty of other issues with your code that will make it messy and hard to handle as it grows. Unless this is purely for learning purposes, I would recommend using one of the many established frameworks out there, or at least using existing composer packages for things like routing etc.

Comment: @M.Eriksson, will do.